# CSS/Javascript flip-animation not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, safari

I have made an animated profile card using CSS and JS, when hovered on it flips and stretches the name and role title up and around and shows the full backside card information. It works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Safari.

It does flip around and shows all contact information when animating but at the end of the animation, the full contact information disappears and only reverts back to the original 'name and role title' on the frontside but upside-down.

The full code and live page can be found here: https://www.leap.co.uk/leadership/index-flip2.html

After reading a few articles, I have tried adding the '-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;' to all 'backface-visibility:hidden;' css but this hasn't worked at all.

I also added a z-index to the 'back' section which fixes it and shows all information at the end of the animation but when it reverts back (after hover is taken off) it still shows instead of just the 'name and role title'.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<body>
<div class="contact">
  <div class="initials">RM</div>
    <div class="flip back">
    <div class="info">
    <div class="name">Randy Marquardt</div>
    <div class="title">Front End Developer</div>
     <hr/>
    <div class="phone">Phone<br/>
      <span>(203)555-5555</span>
      </div>
      <hr/>
    <div class="email">Email<br/>
      <span>rmarquardt.1@gmail.com</span>
      </div>
      <hr/>

    </div>
      <div class="icon-set">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/874640/skype1.svg" class="skype"/>
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/874640/delve1.svg" class="delve" />
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flip front">
    <div class="name">Randy Marquardt</div>
    <div class="title">Front End Developer</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

```
/* CSS */
<!-- language: lang-css -->
html {
  height:100%;
}
body {
  height:100%;
  font-family:"Segoe UI";
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(246,230,180,1) 0%, rgba(237,144,23,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(246,230,180,1) 0%,rgba(237,144,23,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(246,230,180,1) 0%,rgba(237,144,23,1) 100%); 
}
#run {
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  right:20px;
}
.contact {
  position:absolute;
  height:250px;
  width:200px;
  background:#37674b;
  margin:auto;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  text-align:center;
}
.contact .initials {
  margin-top:33px;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:80px;
  font-family:"Segoe UI Light";
  margin-left:10px;
  letter-spacing:10px;
}
.contact .flip {
  width:198px;
  border:1px inset #37674b;
}
.contact .front {
  backface-visibility:hidden;
  position:absolute;
  background:#f0f0f0;
  height:60px;
  bottom:0;
  text-align:center;

}
.contact .front .name {
  margin-top:5px;
  font-size:16px;
  line-height:25px;
  font-weight:600;
}
.contact .front .title {
  font-size:12px;
  font-style:italic;
}
.contact .back {
  backface-visibility:hidden;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:#f0f0f0;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  height:60px;
}
.contact .back .info {
  padding:5px 10px;
}
.contact .back .info .name {
  font-size:18px;
  line-height:25px;
  font-weight:600;
}
.contact .back .info .title {
  font-size:12px;
  font-style:italic;
  /* margin-bottom:20px; */
}
.contact .back .info .phone, .contact .flip .info .email, .contact .flip .info .skype {
  margin-top:20px;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:600;
}
.contact .back .info div span {
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:normal;
}
.contact .icon-set {
  height:45px;
  position:absolute;
  margin:auto;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  text-align:center;
}
.contact .icon-set img {
  width:30px;
  margin:0px 15px;
}
```

```
/* JS */
<!-- language: lang-js -->
  TweenMax.set('.contact', {perspective:700});
  TweenMax.set('.flip', {transformStyle:"preserve-3d"});
  TweenMax.set('.back', {rotationY:-180, rotation:180});
$('.contact').hover(function(){
  var flip = $(this).find('.flip');
  var back = $(this).find('.back');
  var front = $(this).find('.front');
  TweenMax.to(flip, .7, {rotationX:180});
  TweenMax.to([back, front], .7, {height:'100%'});
},
function(){
  var flip = $(this).find('.flip');
  var back = $(this).find('.back');
  var front = $(this).find('.front');
  TweenMax.to(flip, .7, {rotationX:0});
  TweenMax.to([back, front], .7, {height:60});
});
```

I expect the full 'back' information to show on animation completion but when the hover event is taken off, for the 'front' information only to show. This works on all other browsers except safari.